# Bluemix Connection Refused: not authorised, can't register device

Tags: ibm-cloud, mqtt, watson-iot

I have read several tutorials and topics and I did everything as described, but still I am not able to register device.

I have been trying to use MQTTlens and mosquitto but same problem, not authorised

Bellow is command for mosquitto

```
mosquitto_pub -h xwc8vm.messaging.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com -u use-token-auth -P 'YpSP?P98Wwe0pYGXPj' -i 'd:xwc8vm:devicetype:mydevice' -t /iot/x -m '{"d":"heloo"}'
```

This are devices data

```
Organization ID         xwc8vm
Device Type             devicetype
Device ID               mydevice
Authentication Method   token
Authentication Token    XXXXXXXXXX
```

I have used host

```
xwc8vm.messaging.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com
```

and client

```
d:xwc8vm:devicetype:mydevice
```

I even tried using [http://mqtt-helper.mybluemix.net/?cm_sp=dw-bluemix-*-nospace-*-answers](http://mqtt-helper.mybluemix.net/?cm_sp=dw-bluemix-_-nospace-_-answers), but got this error

```
(23:42:45.044)Failed to connect to xwc8vm.messaging.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com:1883. Code: 1, Message: AMQJSC0001E Connect timed out.
```

Everything is configured as here http://heidloff.net/article/useful-mqtt-tools-ibm-watson-iot-bluemix?cm_mc_uid=27677244132415055778021&cm_mc_sid_50200000=1505944109

Comment: Under Security in https://xwc8vm.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com is TLS  optional or required?  And if required, try optional.

Comment: I can't find that, please give me more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check your TLS security setting in your dashboard under the security tab.  New IoT services by default require TLS.  If you are not using TLS then try setting it to optional to see if that resolves the problem.  [image]

Comment: Thanks, after I fixed it I now can publish using mosquitto, but device is not registered and I can't connect using MQTTlens or that test tool. Also, in dashboard not I see this message https://imgur.com/a/Uj4I5

Comment: Please verify your topic.  I see error in log for invalid topic.  message:The topic is not valid: Topic="/iot/x" ClientID="d:xwc8vm:devicetype:mydevice"  Reason="The topic does not match an allowed rule".

Comment: Please tell me where can I verify topic?

Comment: If you are using MQTTLens it has a space for you to provide the topic.

Comment: Yes but where can I find topic in Bluemix, is it some specific topic or generic?

Comment: If you are publishing events from a device you should use topic format such as Daniel stated:  iot-2/evt/event_id/fmt/format_string  Refer to Watson IoT documentation for more information:  https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/IoT/devices/mqtt.html#mqtt

Answer (score 1):

The mosquito command is not complete, you need to specify the port 8883, and the connection is secure by default and you need to specify the server certificate that can be downloaded from below:

https://github.com/ibm-watson-iot/iot-python/blob/master/src/ibmiotf/messaging.pem

So the command should look like:

mosquitto_pub -h xwc8vm.messaging.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com -p 8883 -u "use-token-auth" -P "xxxxxxxxx" -i "d:xwc8vm:device-type:my-device" -t "iot-2/evt/x/fmt/json" -m {"d":"hello"} --cafile messaging.pem -d

messaging.pem file needs to be in the same location as mosquitto_pub file or you can pass the path to it

Note: Please mind the topic format:

"iot-2/evt/x/fmt/json" >>>>> iot-2/evt/event/fmt/event_format

Very important, please edit your post and remove or mask the authentication token

Comment: But in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Glyp2LWjyXc author is not using pem, is it now required?

Comment: yes, now it is. It was made by default to use the secure connection. If you want to use the  unsecured connection then the command should look like:


mosquitto_pub -h xwc8vm.messaging.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com -p 1883 -u "use-token-auth" -P "xxxxxxxxx" -i "d:xwc8vm:device-type:my-device" -t "iot-2/evt/x/fmt/json" -m {"d":"hello"}


But the changes that @ValerieLampkin mentioned are required.

Comment: I am now able to send message using topic you provided and I can see message, but device is still not connected, but disconnected

Comment: @emir that is normal because mosquitto_pub disconnects right after it sends the message. 

mosquitto_pub is a simple MQTT version 3.1 client that will publish a single message on a topic and exit

You can add the client a loop to send multiple messages, then you'll see the client as connected

Comment: just did a quick review of the MQTTLens and it looks like it does not have support for TLS/SSL which is required for secure connections. 
More about this here:
https://github.com/sandro-k/MQTTLensChromeApp/issues/8

Comment: if you want to use an MQTT client to connect, I suggest MQTT.FX

http://mqttfx.jensd.de/index.php/download

I could successfully connect with it over 8883 and 1883

This client stays connected and you can continuously publish messages